# Rspec unit test case getting failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have written some Rspec test cases in my spec/models/season_spec.rb file. They are as:-

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Season do

  it 'should not be without name' do
    Season.new(:name=>nil,:number_of_weeks=>'3',:start_date=>'2012-02-07',:user_id=>'113').should_not be_valid
  end

  it 'should not be without number of weeks' do
    Season.new(:name=>'Apurva',:number_of_weeks=>nil,:start_date=>'2012-02-07',:user_id=>'113').should_not be_valid
  end

  it 'should not be without start_date' do
    Season.new(:name=>'Apurva',:number_of_weeks=>'3',:start_date=>nil,:user_id=>'113').should_not be_valid
  end

  it 'should not be without user_id' do
    Season.new(:name=>'Apurva',:number_of_weeks=>'3',:start_date=>'2012-02-07',:user_id=>nil).should_not be_valid
  end

  it 'should be with valid attributes' do
    Season.new(:name=>'Apurva',:number_of_weeks=>'3',:start_date=>'2012-02-07',:user_id=>'113').should be_valid
  end
end
```

And in my model i have validated these fields as :-

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :name,:number_of_weeks,:start_date,:user_id
end
```

But still the test cases are failed. And it is giving me following output:-

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:138: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 in PATH, mode 040777
FFFFF

Failures:

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:165:in `pending_fixed?': undefined method `pending_fixed?' for #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:0xb6cd03c8> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:19:in `dump_failures'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bundler/gems/rails-27357a6965eb/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:473:in `each_with_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:17:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:17:in `each_with_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:17:in `dump_failures'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/reporter.rb:75:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/reporter.rb:75:in `notify'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/reporter.rb:74:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/reporter.rb:74:in `notify'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/reporter.rb:23:in `conclude'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/reporter.rb:14:in `report'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
    from /usr/bin/rspec:4
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code and stacktraces by indenting them with four spaces when posting here. Thank you.

Comment: Please format as Ryan has indicated - thanks.

Comment: Thank you Mikhali,Ryan and Michael. Sorry for the wrong format. Now please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a typo in the `'should not be without name'` spec. Please check if this is just a typo while typing the quetion here, or in your code.

Second, these tests are pointless since that code is already tested [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/validations_test.rb).

Comment: +1 For advice to not test Rails code. Focus on your business logic.

Comment: @MarkThomas: I think you and I might be wrong here. David Chelmisky says that in general this is obviously the right way to go, however, in case of validations - you do need to add specs / tests, since it is behavior. Check out his comment at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175150/testing-the-relationships-and-methods-in-model-using-rspec#comment11545458_9175150

Comment: Agreed. Validations can be specs, however the tests should be representative of the business requirements. It's just a matter of being careful not to cross the line into testing the validation system itself.