# Testing the relationships and Methods In Model using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec

I m working on rails project and i m new on rails and I want to test my model relationships and methods in model  using rspec. How could I do this my model relationships are like this

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :votes
  validates_presence_of :title, :description
  def published?
    if self.status == "published"
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  def image_present
    if self.image_url
      return self.image_url
    else
      return "/images/image_not_found.jpg"
    end
  end



  def voted
    self.votes.present?
  end
end
```

My idea_spec.rb file is

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Idea do

  it "should have title" do
  Idea.new(:title=>'hello',:description=>'some_desc').should be_valid
  end

  it "should have description" do
  Idea.new(:title=>'hello',:description=>'some_desc').should be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: You only to write specs for code *you* write. Adding tests for features provided by framework is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree in part with @Swanand's comment, but this is a bit more subtle. There is a fundamental difference between associations (which are provided by the framework) and validations (which are also provided by the framework). Associations are structure, which need not be tested directly because it should only exist to support behavior, which should be tested. Validations, however, are behavior, and should be tested. My 2 cents.

Comment: @DavidChelimsky - Sure, I agree. My only concern was, validations are more like DSL here, provided by rails and were already tested when the rails build passed. But I'll take your word for it (I already did actually, by reading The RSpec Book).

Comment: Blog post inspired by this question: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/02/12/validations-are-behavior-associations-are-structure/

Answer (score 5):

If you use shoulda-matchers (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem you can write these as `it{should belong_to(:person)}`

But to be honest I don't get a lot out of these types of test, AR is well tested.

Comment: I use shoulda-matchers and always add such specs, since it's so easy and quite reliable. They test several things including presence of the foreign key in the database etc.

Comment: True, but for uniqueness tests they force you to hit the db when unit testing. I'm not saying it is wrong to use these tests, I'm saying I personally don't get much out them as I have confidence in AR. If you are not confident of the code then you should test it, that's good practice.

Comment: It is indeed wrong to test this. That just shows our distrust for an open source product. The tests are already added and passed. Why do we want to test it again?

Comment: I would say the only purpose to test the relations and validations - is to be sure we did not forget to add them :) But testing with `shoulda-matchers` is more than enough

Comment: @Swanand: I don't distrust AR and don't test ARs behavior. I test the correct usage of a feature provided by AR. There are things you can break, for example, removal of the foreign key in the db, if you rename a class or remove the middle model in a `has_many :through` relationship.

Comment: @iGEL Some really nice arguments for using these kinds of tests. I would say that refactoring a related model is outside the scope of a unit test and would be caught in integration. But then again for the quickness using shoulda matchers you could catch those errors early. Nice one

Comment: @iGEL - Even in that case, you need to test your code that makes use of the relationship, and not test the relationship itself. For example, you removed the middle model in a `has_many :through` - you do that because of a reason (some other part of the code). I'd say, you need to update specs for that code, rather than for `has_many :through` itself. 

My point being, if you have to add tests like the one mentioned in this answer, somewhere you have gone wrong in writing specs and you have uncovered code.

Comment: @Bangline - Those errors must be caught somewhere else. And that somewhere else is specs that describe the behaviour that depends on the associations.

Comment: @Swanand yeah that's why I said it was out of scope for the unit test. I don't think we should just blanket tell people to not test stuff as it is already tested in rails codebase. Testing is more than code coverage; confidence, learning, discovery and understanding come from tests. Heck, even the Agile Development with Rails book tests `presence` validations (another thing I no longer test, but I did when starting with Rails).

Comment: AR doesn't ship with your :person association, so the idea that it's "testing AR" is completely wrong. It could be reasonable to leave that to behaviors that depend on the association. But there are cases where making the test explicit has value - say in the presence of numerous legacy associations, where the people working on the code need to remind themselves which are the "real" associations, and which are going away.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is, you do not. Neither do you test `has_many` or `belongs_to`. The place for these specs / tests is in Rails codebase, and not in your codebase. You `Idea` spec gives you absolutely nothing that Rails does not.

Here are the official tests:

1. [`belongs_to`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/associations/belongs_to_associations_test.rb)
2. [`has_many`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/associations/has_many_associations_test.rb)

Edit: Please read @DavidChelimsky's comment above.

Comment: looks like you haven't got question right... he is not asking testing of base association methods. He wants presence test of associations inside his own model and that can be done by using `shoulda-matchers`

Comment: He says "I want to test my model relationships and methods in model". Also, what is the difference between "base association methods" and "associations inside his own model"? Aren't they the same?

Comment: i mean to say base methods `has_many, belongs_to` and associations means `belongs_to :person` which is he wanted to test.